# Iptables equivalent command in OSX

Tags: macos, unix

Need to do dscp marking on a mac machine

Here is iptables command I use on linux box

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -j DSCP --set-dscp 0x10
```

What's the iptables equivalent in OSX for above command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "equivalent" of iptables on macOS is pf (packet filter). Refer to the manual page for the configuration file here:

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/pf.conf.5.html

In this case you want to use the "tos" option, as this is the way you set the QoS parameters similar to your --set-dscp option for iptables.

The configuration line could look something like this:

```
scrub out on $WAN proto tcp set-tos 0x10
```